# Sqlite retaining huge memory even after transactions

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, memory-management, ram

I am using sqlite browser to run some queries. In case of queries which return huge data, sqlite consumes large amount of RAM and does not free it until the browser is closed / killed. Is there a way to free memmory without killing the process?

Comment: Does the same happen with the command-line shell?

Comment: @CL. No. It's happening only on browser

Comment: Then dont use that browser.

Comment: @CL. Is it fault fo the browser only OR sqlite consumes memory this way only?

Comment: It would be possible, in theory, for the browser to configure SQLite to use more memory (e.g., by increasing the cache size). However, in any case, it's the browser's fault.

Comment: @CL. I tried to analyze the memory usage by building a java application. I created an exe from my java application. When I run query from this application, the exe also starts consuming memory when queries are run and blocks it (does not release it)